# Fiddler JSON plugin (other than JSON Viewer)

Tags: json, fiddler

Does anyone have any recommendations for an offline JSON viewer with a Fiddler2 plugin aside from the example I talk about below?

I really enjoy the ability of the [Json Viewer's](https://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/%22JSON%20Viewer's%22) ability to act as a plugin to Fiddler 2, however I have run into some problems with the program I don't really like. For example, it can't handle unexpected ends like [this online viewer](http://json.parser.online.fr/) can. Additionally, while it's "copy value" function allows me to convert an object polluted with escape characters back into a readable json, it seems to take far too long.

Example of what I might encounter:

```
{"args":"[[{\"method\":\"someServerMethod\",\"request\":\"{\\\"someStuffToRequest\\\",[],[],{\\\"somePropertiesOfStuff\\\":{\\\"ExampleItem\\\":\\\"ExampleValue\\\"}},[{\\\"moreProperties\\\":\\\"objectName\\\",\\\"property\\\":value}]]\"}]]","id":"someIDValue","method":"otherStuff"}
```

Comment: Modern versions of Fiddler have a built-in JSON viewer. What problem do you have with that one?

Comment: While my version of Fiddler does have a built-in JSON viewer it doesn't have the functionality of the previously mentioned example. For instance, I can not extract the value of a property which is a JSON wrapped in quotation marks (but is not recognized as part of the parent JSON) and paste it back into the viewer's "text" window.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't imagine what that would look like. Maybe provide a repro or screenshot?

Comment: Added an example of what I might see in a fiddler debug between our client and server side applications.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm not a fan of Fiddler's JSON viewer.  For example, I can't tell between a string an a number when looking at the JSON viewer.  I prefer a formatted string, like the output you get here (http://jsbeautifier.org/).  Charles proxy provides a nicely formatted JSON viewer, which you can then copy and paste into a text editor.  It would be nice if we can replace the default JSON viewer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try JsonEditor inspector:  http://jsoneditor.codeplex.com/